# Embed google-plus in GWT

Tags: gwt, google-plus

I am trying to embed Google-Plus into my GWT Application. I would like it to be embedded into a HorizontalPanel. I did read [+1button developers google](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/). I didn't find any post about this particular problem in stackoverflow. My problem might be that I don't understand how to include the js into a GUI component. I would appreciate an Example of how to add the Google+ code into a Panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

Documentation:

```
 <!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
 <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
 <g:plusone></g:plusone>
```

in GWT:

```
private void drawPlusOne() {
    String s = "<g:plusone href=\"http://urltoplusone.com\"></g:plusone>";
    HTML h = new HTML(s);
    somePanel.add(h);

    // You can insert a script tag this way or via your .gwt.xml
    Document doc = Document.get();
    ScriptElement script = doc.createScriptElement();
    script.setSrc("https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js");
    script.setType("text/javascript");
    script.setLang("javascript");
    doc.getBody().appendChild(script);
  }
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. I didn't try it in Production mode but I am assuming it will work aswell. If not it would be a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never embedded the +1 button in GWT, but the linked article seems pretty self explanatory.

In the section "A Simple Button", it indicates that the simplest way of implementing GooglePlus integration is to add this:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" />
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
```

First, the `<script>` tag should be included in your `.gwt.xml` file.

Then I'd implement the `<g:plusone></g:plusone>` like this:

```
public class GPlusOne extends SimplePanel {
    public GPlusOne () {
        super((Element)Document.get().createElement("g:plusone").cast());
    }
}
```

(Note that this code is untested, but it's based on the simple concept that a `SimplePanel` can be extended to compile as any HTML element.)

Then you'd use the new `GPlusOne` element wherever you'd want the button to show.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. I don't like putting things in my .gwt.xml since I like to keep it clean. But if there is no other way I will do it this way and do further research into putting js somewhere else. Thanks so far.

Comment: As far as I know, external JS is supposed to go in the .gwt.xml. Alternatively, you could put the `<script>` tag in the html landing page itself. (Personally I don't like messing with the landing page because I like to keep it clean.)

Comment: I put the script in <module> is that right? I get the exception:       [ERROR] Element 'script' beginning on line 18 contains unexpected attribute 'type'
      [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onUnexpectedAttribute(DefaultSchema.java:72)
 at

Comment: `<script src="..." />` is all you need. Yes, it goes in the `<module>` @Martin

Comment: This did not work in production or debug mode. It did not give an exception. I appreciate your help. It's getting late so I will work on it tomorrow again.

Comment: Should check that the element `<g:plusone>` was actually added to the DOM (using Chrome developer tools or Firebug or whatever) and check to make sure that the javascript was actually loaded. If either of these things doesn't happen, it won't show.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do it:

Follow this example to have the button work on invocation on a normal html page (you can try one here http://jsfiddle.net/JQAdc/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
    {"parsetags": "explicit"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gPlusBtn(id, params) {
        /* window.alert("searching for "+ id +" with params: "+ params) */
        paramsObj = eval( '('+params+')' );
        gapi.plusone.render(id, paramsObj );
    }
// params is here just for a reference to simulate what will come from gwt
 params = '{href:"http://1vu.fr", size:"tall"}';

</script>
</head>

<body>
taken from http://jsfiddle.net/JQAdc/
    <div id="gplus" />
    <button onclick="gPlusBtn('gplus', params)">show!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can call a native method to trigger the button display on Activity start (if you're using MVP).

```
protected native void plusOneButton(String id, String params) /*-{
    $wnd.gPlusBtn(id, params);
}-*/;
```

You can have multiple buttons with different urls, that's why id is left as a parameter.

**NOTE:** for me the raw HTML works on localhost, but the GWT version. I have to deploy to the server to be able to see the results

Comment: I also discovered this library. Which might be of help: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-socialmedia 

I'd recommend to use individual classes like https://code.google.com/p/gwt-socialmedia/source/browse/trunk/gwt-socialmedia-library/src/main/java/com/tinesoft/gwt/socialmedia/client/google/plusone/GooglePlusOneButtonImpl.java
to get inspired. The lib seems invasive in its architecture